# ant design input direction when is empty

Tags: reactjs, input, antd, right-to-left

How can I set input direction to `rtl` when input value is empty but `auto` otherwise.

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-input-direction-lofk3

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this. I put a useState to handle the value of the input and react upon it with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-input-direction-forked-dogr1